# Is it possible to specify Python architecture when building with pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, x86, pyinstaller, arm64

I work on old intel-based Mac. We use pyinstaller to build distributives. They work on intel-based machines but on newer Macs we see

```
zsh: killed /Users/...../our_distr_folder
```

it seems, x86 version of Python is included in distr.
is it possible to replace it with arm64e?
or maybe it's possible to create a venv with arm64 Python (that will not work on my machine)?

I have both of them installed:

```
>> file $(which /usr/bin/python3)
```

says:

```
/usr/bin/python3 (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/python3 (for architecture arm64e): Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```